# How can I disable javascript popups/alerts in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, userscripts, alert

Sorry if it's been asked. I've already found several solutions that aren't working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I don't want to disable all javascript, only Javascript alert boxes. The ones that pop up and force you to click OK or X to close them.

I've found user scripts that claim to do this (example: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/58252 ). I've put chrome on the dev channel, start chrome with the --enable-user-scripts switch, the script shows up as installed.

But I still get the alert boxes.

An example alert box that isn't getting disabled is at http://wordswithfriends.net/ - put in any garbage word into the word validator on the right sidebar. You get a popup telling you it's not a word.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only way to disable the alert boxes is to install either an extension or a userscript.  The userscript you linked is for Firefox Greasemonkey and will not work on Chrome.

Additionally, [the misbehaving page you cite](http://wordswithfriends.net/) is sneaky and runs that "word validator" in an `iframe` with code that fires the `alert()` immediately upon iframe reload.

But here's a userscript that defeats it:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Wordswithfriends, Block javascript alerts
// @match       http://wordswithfriends.net/*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

addJS_Node (null, null, overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions);

function overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions () {
    window.alert = function alert (message) {
        console.log (message);
    }
}

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

---

If you really want to disable ALL `alerts()` on ALL pages (Not recommended), then delete the `// @match` line.

Comment: I accepted this answer so hard my mouse exploded. Works like a charm. Thank you very much ^^

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad to help.

Comment: Why is not recommended to disable all alerts? I never came accross useful alerts except "do you really want to exit this tab" on unsaved progress pages.

Comment: Doesn't work if the page shows alerts during load.

Comment: @riv, open a new question if you have a case where it doesn't work. Be sure to provide a complete recipe for duplicating the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is [at least one extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alert-control/ofjjanaennfbgpccfpbghnmblpdblbef?hl=en) for that in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/block%20alerts). Works for me, even though it sounds a bit suspect that it has an optional support by ads mode you can disable in its settings page. (I didn't find the setting, but figured it couldn't hurt null routing `api.s13.us`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tool for this and don't want to mess with user scripts - there is nice tool that can handle any annoying popup on a Windows system - **ClickOff**. You can download it from [here](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/clickoff.html). I checked, it works with "Changes you made may not be saved" alert for SharePoint sites.

Comment: this sounds interesting, as annoying error popups would be nice to remove in general. Does it let you specify exactly what sort of dialogues you want to automatically OK/cancel, or does it somehow choose them by itself?

Comment: Yes, you can specify what dialogues to close and the button to click.