# Avoid alert box from web browser

Tags: browser, javascript, popups

We develop our own dashboard using iFrame and show multiple dashboard using our platform and switch periodically to another iFrame using Java Script.

Sometimes the dashboard will show an alert box popup with the message

[image]

These popups are annoying us because when they show we need to remote in to that dashboard and click ok. If we do not click ok, the iFrame cannot switch to another dashboard.

The page at bi.smu runs on Tomcat server as a webservices to our MSTR server and the session are already increased to 60 seconds.

How we can disable the pop up message?

Comment: The question is rather unclear (for example, what is a "strength issue on our Microstrategy"?). In addition to that, it looks like a software development problem, which is off-topic here. Please  expand and edit it to make it a clear on-topic quesiton.

Comment: @sleske Thanks for your feedback. The question are already edited to 'How we can disable the pop up message? is there any software or addons on the browser?'

Comment: Thanks, that's better. I further edited to focus the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages you are seeing are probably displayed using a JavaScript alert box (by using the JavaScript function `alert()`).

JavaScript alerts can be disabled in the browser, however most browser do not have a built-in setting to do this, rather you will have to disable it using JavaScript, by overriding the `alert()` function. How to best do this depends on the browser you use. See for example [JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert) and [How can I disable javascript popups/alerts in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/455863/how-can-i-disable-javascript-popups-alerts-in-chrome) for details.

In addition to that, most modern browsers will allow you to disable alerts from sites that show too many of them. For example, in Firefox, if a page shows more than three alerts, the alerts will get a checkbox saying "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs". If you check the box and dismiss it, the page will be blocked from creating further dialogs. However, I believe this will only remain in force until the page is reloaded, so it is not a permanent measure.